# CSS modal images

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I need some help when showing an image in a modal, I want the image to scale up and down maintaining its ratio.

If the image is smaller than the window then show it all

If the image is larger than the window enlarge it as much as possible to fill the window maintaining scale (no scrolling)

Also I'd like to have the body of the website darker and unable to scroll when a modal is opened, but I can't figure how to do so. Here's my HTML and CSS code (I know it doesn't work well when on small resolutions but it's not my requirement for now):

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

h1, h4{
    color:#0B486B;
}

#container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 3% 0 3%;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;  
    background-color: #E0E4CC;
}

#footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #E0E4CC;
}

#sidebar {
    padding-top: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #69D2E7;
    text-align: center;
}

#btngroup {
    padding-top: 20%;
}

#grid {
    padding: 0 2% 2% 2%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #A7DBD8;
}

#gridrow {
    padding: 3% 0 0 0;
    height:50%;
}

#gridcol {
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 92%;
    max-height: 92%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;  
    top: 0;  
    bottom: 0;  
    left: 0;  
    right: 0;  
    margin: auto;
}

img:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#myModal {
    display: none;
}

#modalDialog {
    margin: auto;
}

#modalContent {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#modalBody {
    padding:3px;
}

#imgModal {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    cursor: default;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>MyBootstrap</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container" class="row">
    <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-3 sidenav">
      <h1>HELLO<br>WORLD</h1>
      <ul id="btngroup" class="nav nav-stacked">
        <li><a href="#section1"><h4>Pictures</h4></a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2"><h4>Music</h4></a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3"><h4>About me</h4></a></li>
      </ul><br>
    </div>
    <div id="grid" class="col-md-9">
        <div id="gridrow" class="row">
            <div id="gridcol" class="col-md-4">
                <img src="http://www.avionslegendaires.net/wp-content/uploads/images/dossier/F-15-leurre-thermique.jpg" class="img-rounded" onclick="onClick(this)"/>
            </div>
            <div id="gridcol" class="col-md-4">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" class="img-rounded" onclick="onClick(this)"/>
            </div>
            <div id="gridcol" class="col-md-4">
                <img src="https://photos.smugmug.com/Landscapes/i-mjXhFCT/0/c99cf534/XL/IMG_7608-Edit-XL.jpg" class="img-rounded" onclick="onClick(this)"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="gridrow" class="row">
            <div id="gridcol" class="col-md-4">
                <img src="http://img.171u.com/image/1609/2607005498770.jpg" class="img-rounded" onclick="onClick(this)"/>
            </div>
            <div id="gridcol" class="col-md-4">
                <img src="https://photos.smugmug.com/Landscapes/i-mjXhFCT/0/c99cf534/XL/IMG_7608-Edit-XL.jpg" class="img-rounded" onclick="onClick(this)"/>
            </div>
            <div id="gridcol" class="col-md-4">
                <img src="http://www.tappingforabundance.com/wp-content/uploads/slider1.jpg" class="img-rounded" onclick="onClick(this)"/>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal" onclick="this.style.display='none'">
  <div id="modalDialog" class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div id="modalContent" class="modal-content" style="background-color:#000000">
      <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">
        <img id="imgModal" class="img-rounded" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
<div id="footer">
    <h1>Footer</h1>
</div>



<script>
// Modal Image Gallery
function onClick(element) {
  document.getElementById("imgModal").src = element.src;
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "flex";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.doNotScroll{
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100%;
}

....
$(document).on('click', '.img-rounded', function(){
    $('BODY, HTML').addClass('doNotScroll');
})

...

$(document).on('click', '#myModal', function(){
    $('BODY, HTML').removeClass('doNotScroll');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

disable scrolling Body:

```
BODY,HTML{
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100%;
}
```

For dark Background place a div directly in body:

```
DIV.cover.inactiv{ 
 display: none; 
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 z-index: 10 // play with it
}

DIV.cover.activ{
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: about the scrolling part, I need it only when the modal is showing, I tried assigning it with JS but I didn't succeed, can you show me a solution for my case?